# Different static front pages according to users role

Tags: wordpress

I would like to display a different homepage according to users role. There are some function like is_front_page() or show_on_front() that can be used but I don't know how. 
And  the best would be to display the front page according to users roles and also their locale language. For example : if user is editor and his default locale language is ... then the homepage is....
If you have any idea,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "User Role Editor" plugin to create the user roles.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

**Get current user role**

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user_role = $current_user->roles[0];
```

**Redirect the URL by role**

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {    
  if ($current_user_role == "Administrator"){
    wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/en/' );
  }
  if ($current_user_role == "Author"){
    wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/jp/' );
  }
  else{
    if ($current_user_role == "Administrator"){
      wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/' );
    }
  }
}
```

So, you can check the condition before redirect the default specific user front page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already use a role plugin called "Advanced Access Management". I am afraid there would be conflicts between both.

Comment: If you have alreday created the user role, just use the code **Get current user role** and no need to install another user role plugin.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I read many tutorials but did not find any solution. how can we assign a homepage according to the user role?

Comment: If you didn't use the plugin for the languages, you can use this.
**[https://wordpress.org/plugins/xili-language/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/xili-language/)**

Comment: Before you check the if condition, you output the $current_user_role first. Is it "editor" or "Editor"?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried for an editor, but this did not work :(

Comment: When I add the 2 first lines code (of Get Current User Role), the front displays nothing.

Comment: Ok, it finally works. I changed details in code and now it's Ok. Thanks for everything. Here's the code: function homepage_template_redirect() {
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user_role = $current_user->roles[0];
if ( is_front_page() ) {    
  if ($current_user_role == "editor"){
    wp_redirect(get_page_link(1194) );
    exit;
  }
}
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'homepage_template_redirect' );

Comment: Hello, I voted but as I am new the vote is recorded but not displayed. Thanks again.